# Compiling Mongoose's hello.c under Windows

Tags: c, windows, mongoose-web-server

I am trying to compile the included [hello.c](https://github.com/valenok/mongoose/blob/master/examples/hello.c) example from [Mongoose](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) under Windows. I am using the Microsoft Visual command prompt and I have copied the mongoose.c and mongoose.h to the same directory as the hello.c example.

When I write "cl hello.c" I get the following output/error:

```
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

hello.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:hello.exe
hello.obj
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mg_stop referenced in function _main
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mg_start referenced in function _main
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mg_printf referenced in function _begin_request_handler
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _snprintf referenced in function _begin_request_handler
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mg_get_request_info referenced in function _begin_request_handler

hello.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals
```

There is a [Makefile](https://github.com/valenok/mongoose/blob/master/examples/Makefile) included with the examples and I have tried to use the Makefile to do the build, but do not understand how to do this. If i try "nmake hello.exe". I get the following output/error:

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cl -W -Wall -I.. -pthread -g hello.c
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cl : Command line error D8004 : '/W' requires an argument
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

**EDIT**
I have also tried the to compile like instructed in the [user manual](https://github.com/valenok/mongoose/blob/master/UserManual.md#embedding) which on windows should translate to "cl hello.c mongoose.c -o hello.exe" but then I get the following error message:

```
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'o' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
hello.c
mongoose.c
Generating Code...
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:hello.exe
/out:hello.exe
hello.obj
mongoose.obj
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _snprintf referenced in function _begin_request_handler
hello.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Does anyone have suggestions on what steps needs to be taken in order to compile the hello.c example for Mongoose under Windows?

Comment: `-W -Wall -I.. -pthread -g` look like arguments for gcc (except it should probably be '-lpthread' there), and `cl` seems to agree, looking at error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the issue with my third try above was that "_snprintf" has been depreached and replaced by "_snprintf_s" in the C version used by Visual Studio 10. I thus replaced the one occurence of "_snprintf" with _snprintf_s and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are not specifying the linkage to the library (DLL, whatever it actually is) for mongoose.  That's why you have the unresolved externals.  It needs to know where to find them so that the executable can locate them at runtime (if it's linked dynamically) or include the code in the .exe (if done statically).